# How can I have 2 Google Translate widgets on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently working on a WordPress website, where I would like to have two Google Translate widgets on the website.  The scenarios, I wish to create, are as follows:

**Desktop/Laptop/Tablet:**

I would like the Google Translate Widget to appear in the very top bar.

**Mobile Devices:**

I would like the Google Translate Widget to be hidden from the Top Bar and displayed in the Footer.

**What I have done to date ...**

In the `header.php`, I have entered the following code, where appropriate:

```
<div id="google_translate">
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, autoDisplay: false, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'}, 'google_translate_element');
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  #google_translate {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The above PHP/CSS etc, successfully adds the Google Translate Widget to the Top Bar for large screens, while hiding the Widget on mobile devices.

**Where the Problem occurs ...**

I then paste the same Google Translate Widget code, into the `footer.php` file.  Before I am able to work on the CSS, the Google Translate Widget does not appear within the Footer but right next to the Google Translate Widget in the header's top bar.

How can this be and how can I resolve this issue, so that I am able to work on the CSS as to hide the Widget on larger screens?

Comment: Are you pasting the same code with the same "id" attributes? May be that is the problem...

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with targeting ids `google_translate`. HTML standard says all ids should be unique. Can you share the google translate code? Perhaps you could adjust it to look for `google_translate_2`.  Additionally you could write some javascript to move the element on certain screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I tried 'class' alternative and changing the the 'id' attributes.  Unfortunately, when I do this, the Widget just completely disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a javascript solution you could try plugging into your page. You would need sort out ids for your `header` and `footer` but I think this could get you started.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function placeTranslateWidget() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    // if the screen is small move the html element to the footer.
    if(w < 991){ // 991 would be the width of the mobile break point.
      document.getElementById('google_translate').appendChild( document. getElementById('footer') )
    }else{
      document.getElementById('google_translate').appendChild( document. getElementById('header') )
    }
}
// run this function after page loads;
placeTranslateWidget();
// runs the function any time the body is resized.
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onresize = function() {placeTranslateWidget()};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Google widget contains IDs in its markup, and IDs **[must be unique throughout the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**. Duplicating the widget would also duplicate the ID. And failing to have unique IDs will cause JavaScript selectors to only work with the first ID.

As such, considering you simply want to *move* your widget on a mobile view, the best way to solve this would be with **[`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. You'd need to share your whole markup for an *absolute* solution, but the general premise would be to simply move the widget to the bottom of the screen at a certain breakpoint, with something like:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  .widget {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">Widget</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

By default, the widget would be above the content, but for mobile devices it will appear at the bottom of the page.